# How to load specific URLs, delete live server trash, and schedule server backup on a local mac system instead of running cron jobs on the main server?

Tags: cron, backup, scheduled-tasks, launchd

I want to load specific URLs of my website on my local Mac system at 11 AM and 8 PM everyday, and get the server backup at 10 PM everyday using my Mac instead of setting up the cron jobs on a live server. Additionally I found some online information on how to use Launchd to run applications on specific times. For example, com.tjluoma.SuprSetr.plist file in ~/Library/LaunchAgents as below, and then running launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.tjluoma.SuprSetr.plist in terminal.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>AbandonProcessGroup</key>
    <true/>
    <key>Disabled</key>
    <false/>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.tjluoma.SuprSetr</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/usr/bin/open</string>
        <string>-a</string>
        <string>SuprSetr</string>
    </array>
    <key>StartCalendarInterval</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>Hour</key>
            <integer>3</integer>
            <key>Minute</key>
            <integer>55</integer>
        </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

1. Could you please give me your opinion if Launchd is appropriate enough to fulfill my goal? If yes, how to add the specific URL address to .plist file?
2. Also, is there a better way to solve this problem?
3. How can I authorize my local IP address to be able to login to the live server to perform the required tasks?